# Where can I find an online manual for the Yongnuo RF-605N?

Tags: wireless-triggers, wireless-flash, yongnuo

The manual that came with the Yongnuo RF-605N is very small and hard for me to read, I am get old and losing the potential of my eyes. Anyone know if there is any manual online where it can be download, or buy books or CD/DVD about this Yongnuo 605N? If there is any answer to my question please write me at: NYSTalents@optimum.net Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can find a PDF online at this link:

http://www.yongnuorussia.com/upload/download/yongnuo/RF605_Usermanual.pdf

However, the English in it appears to be mostly machine-translated from the original Chinese.

Given that these are manual triggers, the Canon and Nikon versions are probably identical, except for the pin pattern on the foot.  You're unlikely to find any published material/tutorials on using them.  Most of the advice you can find will be online from other users or reviews.

One place you can consider going for advice and help is [the photography-on-the.net messageboard's Flash and Studio Lighting forum](http://photography-on-the.net/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=35).  Another would be [the Strobist group discussions on flickr](https://www.flickr.com/groups/strobist/discuss).